# why are the first few characters of a DSA Private Key similar?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, key-generation, dsa

I noticed most DSA private keys often start with the same few characters, `MIIBvAIBAAKBgQD` .

For example, generate a private key on Ubuntu, by running:

`ssh-keygen -t dsa -N '' -f /tmp/id_dsa`

This results in a private key file that begins with something like:

`-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----

MIIBvAIBAAKBgQD...`

The first 16 characters are suspiciously similar.
I expect `ssh-keygen` is using a random nonce before beginning encipherment.  Assuming `ssh-keygen` is using a random nonce, **why are the first few characters of the DSA Private Key files similar?**

---

Using a script, I found that uniqueness ("randomness", good entropy, etc.) begins at the 17th character.

```
leading char count  1 - unique combinations   1 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  2 - unique combinations   1 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  3 - unique combinations   1 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  4 - unique combinations   1 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  5 - unique combinations   2 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  6 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  7 - unique combinations   6 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  8 - unique combinations   5 among 100 generated keys
leading char count  9 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 10 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 11 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 12 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 13 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 14 - unique combinations   4 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 15 - unique combinations   7 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 16 - unique combinations  87 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 17 - unique combinations 100 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 18 - unique combinations 100 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 19 - unique combinations 100 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 20 - unique combinations 100 among 100 generated keys
leading char count 21 - unique combinations 100 among 100 generated keys
...
```

I used the following bash code to determine this

```
keyf=/tmp/id_dsa-${RANDOM}
for upto in {1..35} ; do
    keys="${keyf}-${upto}"
    rm -f "${keys}" &>/dev/null
    for i in {0..99} ; do
        rm "${keyf}" &>/dev/null
        ssh-keygen -t dsa -N '' -f "${keyf}" &>/dev/null
        sed '2q;d' "${keyf}" | cut -b 1-"${upto}" >> "${keys}"
    done
    keys_count_all=$(cat "${keys}" | wc -l)
    keys_count_uniq=$(sort -u "${keys}" | wc -l)
    printf "leading char count %2d - unique combinations %3d among %3d generated keys\n" ${upto} ${keys_count_uniq} ${keys_count_all}
done
rm "${keyf}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DSA private key file has a *structure* to it, it's not simply a random number (or two). Within the PEM encoded data (base64 + delimiters) is a DER encoded ASN.1 binary structure.
[ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) is a system independent way to encode data (think of it like a "binary XML"). Strictly, only the first *two bytes* of a DSA key encoded this way are fixed, but for a *given key size*  more can be said. Note there are no "magic numbers" in the underlying data structure.

A [DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) key pair has 5 distinct components: P, Q, G, public key part, private key part.
Digging into the source of OpenSSL (used by OpenSSH for this) `crypto/dsa/dsa_asn1.c`:

```
ASN1_SEQUENCE_cb(DSAPrivateKey, dsa_cb) = {
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, version, LONG),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, p, BIGNUM),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, q, BIGNUM),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, g, BIGNUM),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, pub_key, BIGNUM),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(DSA, priv_key, BIGNUM)
} ASN1_SEQUENCE_END_cb(DSA, DSAPrivateKey)
```

Which corresponds with what you'll see with `openssl asn1parse -in id_dsa` (though note if you use `openssl dsa -in id_dsa -noout -text` the version field is omitted, and the *order is changed* to priv, pub, P, Q, G).

Taking a look at the parsed ASN.1 output:

```
0:d=0  hl=4 l= 830 cons: SEQUENCE          
4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
7:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :DFA34F1D[...]
```

In the [DER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules#DER_encoding) form of ASN.1 each item of data is a `(type tag,length,data)` triple. In the above `asn1parse` output the leading columns indicate the offset, `d=` depth, `hl=`header length (size of type tag and length fields), and `l=` data length. (In non-DER forms it can be a little more complicated, but we don't need to worry about that here.)

If we unwrap the base64 we can see the DER binary format:

```
$ openssl dsa -in id_dsa -outform DER | hexdump -C | head -1

00000000  30 82 03 3e 02 01 00 02  82 01 01 00 df a3 4f 1d  |0..>........ß£O.|
                                            ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
```

You can expect the leading bytes to be reasonably static (SEQUENCE "container" + version=0), though the sequence size will be dependent on the DSA key size. The DSA "P" (`^^`) is the long prime (1024, 2048 or 3072 bits) is next, so for a given fixed key size its header of 4 bytes will also be reasonably static. This gives a total of 11 reasonably static bytes for a defined key size (technically *sizes*, e.g. 2048,256 for p,q). A complication here is minor variations in the size of encoded integers: an extra 0-byte padding will be added to ensure positive integers (leading bit must be 0).

You analysed the [base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) data, those 11 reasonably static bytes become encoded in the leading 15 characters of base64 output (11*8/6 =14.66) with two bits of the random P also found in the 15th character (given the padding condition, those two bits will be zero about 75% of the time anyway).
I believe this agrees with your data.

Note the minor increase in variation around the 5th/6th base64 encoded character: this corresponds with the low-octet of the total structure size (4th DER byte), the size has minor variations for fixed key sizes due to the 50% chance of leading 0-padding on each of the 5 encoded DSA integers.

An alternate format for keys is [PKCS#8](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc5208), this omits the public key part, but it adds the [`dsaEncryption` OID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370#section-3.1) so at least the structure is a little less enigmatic:

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -in id_dsa -topk8 -nocrypt | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 589 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=4 l= 558 cons: SEQUENCE          
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim: OBJECT            :dsaEncryption
   20:d=2  hl=4 l= 545 cons: SEQUENCE          
   24:d=3  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :DFA34F[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DSA key is stored as a [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules#DER_encoding)-encoded data structure which is in turn [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded.  The first 16 bytes are basically the encoding of a description of what's in the file; the rest of the file is the key itself.

Comment: but I've seen multiple DSA keys that start with AAAAB3NzaC1 followed by kc3MAAACBA, which adds up to 21 characters.  So I don't think the key (which ought to be much more random) starts after the character, as this answer indicates.  I do believe there is a header, as noted by mr.spuratic's answer, but what I'm doubting is that the header's length is only 16 bytes.